# Printscreen the active Window only?

Tags: windows

Is software like gadwin printscreen the only way to take a screenshot of active window or is there an easier way? I do not need full screenshots for a slideshow and cropping over 50 images may take a long time. I am long time Linux user and I am used to the scrot tool, but cannot find something the same for windows...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Printscreen</kbd> should do the trick!

then simply paste your image in paint or the image editing application of your choice and save it, no cropping required.

Comment: Using Windows since 5 years but still wasn't aware of this thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Alt + Printscreen does the job, but then you have to paste into some app - and save.

Use [Cropper](http://www.codeplex.com/cropper) in stead, which will not interfer with the normal PrintScreen-behaviour - but add a feature that saves the captured image directly to a folder of your choise in jpg for instance. Works great when you want to do many screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) allows you do this.

Go to Options->Capture/Screenshot (or press 'C'), and then select the Capture Area you want (e.g. foreground window), then start.

Select the window you want to capture, then press Ctrl-F11. Irfanview will then come to the front, with your captured window as an image, ready for you to save and/or edit as needed.

Answer (score 1):

For Vista and Windows 7 I can recommend [WindowClippings](http://www.windowclippings.com/) as that program is able to produce PNGs with transparency where the glass frame is. Thus you don't have parts of other windows shining through, you get the round corners cleanly cut out and you get the DWM drop shadow for free. Definitely useful, although not as much for people using legacy Windows versions.

It comes at a small price, however.